# Select rows using a count condition inside a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a table, MyTable(ID, Type, Date). Column 'Type' can have a value of 1 or 2.

Top 'x' rows, ordered by 'Date' and satisfying the following condition, have to be selected.('a' and 'b' are integer values)

The selected 'x' rows can contain only a maximum of 'a' Type 1 rows and 'b' Type 2 rows.(If a+b < x, then only a+b rows have to be selected.)

I might be completely wrong but I have an idea of doing this by having count() inside a WHERE clause. But I am not sure of how to do it.

How do I go about this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Example -

[image]

x = 5

**Case 1:**
a = 5, b = 5

Result: Rows 1,2,3,4,5

**Case 2:**
a = 4, b = 1

Result: Rows 1,2,4,6,8

**Case 3:**
a = 1, b = 5

Result: Rows 1,2,3,5,7

**Case 4:**
a = 2, b = 1

Result: Rows 1,2,4

Comment: Can you clarify your question with example data, or what you expect to see? This can probably be easily done with a `HAVING` clause after your `WHERE` clause, however without a clear example it's hard to say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by nesting a UNION inside another query:

```
select top @x *
from (

   select top @a *
   from table 
   where type = '1'
   order by [date]

  union

   select top @b *
   from table
   where type = '2'
   order by [date]

) t
order by [date]
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Just change `top @..` to `top (@..)`
and use `union all`, because you are guaranteed to get distinct rows.